# Where to transform store property in Redux/ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have the following setup

*someReducer.ts*

```
export interface State {
   someProp: MyModel;
}
// some action listeners ..
// 
//

export const getProp = (state: State) => state.someProp;
```

*selector.ts*

```
export const getProperty = createSelector(getState, fromSomeReducer.getProperty);
```

Now say in my components I want to use a transformed version of this `someProp` like

`myProp = this.store.pipe(select(fromSelector.getProperty)).pipe(map(val => //some logic here));`

Now this mapping logic can be long, and I dont want to be duplicating this code in several components.

Where does it make sense the most to put this mapping?

I add it to the *reducer* like this

`export const getMapped = (state: State) => state.map(val => // some logic);` and then I get this in the selector.

Is this the recommended approach?

Comment: Your reducer doesn't really look like a reducer..? In your reducer you only listen to actions, modify state and return a new state slice. Your selectors are used to compose data from your state...

Comment: Yes yes, I didnt include the stuff related to actions in the reducer I have. So you recommend having that data mapping in the selector? how can I extract that data in the selector?

Comment: well - it depends. If the data you are receiving (maybe through an effect) is not in an ideal format, you can use your reducer to put it in the state the way you like it. However, if that data is okay - and you just want to get certain formats of data in your components (maybe even combinations of state slices) - then a selector is the recommended approach.

Comment: The data is OK, but i want to basically transform it to another model using some mappings.

Comment: It's a bit vague as to what you mean with 'some mappings' - but in general - a selector is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you are looking for [Selector](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)

```js
export const mySelector = createSelector(
  getProperty,
  val => // Your logic go here
)
```

You can now use it

```js
this.store.pipe(select(fromSelector.mySelector)).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.